# 3 Way Light Switch on Stairs

Tags: electrical

I currently have a 3 way light switch in my stairwell.  One at the bottom and one at the top of the stairs.  I recently added a light fixture to the bottom of the stairs but need some help wiring it up.  I have been rewiring the whole house but the 3 ways a bit confusing to me.  Power comes in from the light fixture at the top of the stairs. Here is a diagram of what I have and what I am trying to do.  Any help would be great.  [image]

[image]
Can I tie into the wiring leaving the original light before it reaches the switch on the left?

Comment: You can't do that. 3-ways do not work that way.

Comment: Nope, sorry, can't do that one either.  You need netural and switched-hot, and neutral is not at either 3-way location.

Comment: So it has to be from the power source feeding the original light.

Comment: Yes, unless you are able to change the cable in the wall.  You cannot just run a loose wire, the cable needs to be changed.  If you could change the cable from the lamp to switch1 to a /3 cable, that would allow you to feed it from switch1.

Comment: That might be easier for me to do.  I'm working with plaster and lathe walls and have been just knocking holes in the wall and will patch them later.  However, I would have to punch a lot of holes to get the cable from the bottom light to the top light as they are on different ceilings.  I can however get to the top light switch without too much difficulty.

Comment: If you can get /3 cable between lamp and 2story switch, you may also be able to find a setup with smart switches that would allow you to feed from 1story switch.

Comment: Your updated picture would not work.  That white wire in the first switch box is not a neutral.  It is marked with black tape because it is acting as a hot (switch loop).  Again, the ONLY box in that diagram that has a neutral is the one with the light fixture.

Comment: What type of smart switches are we talking about Harper?  Understood JPhi1618.  Looking like the only way to make it work for sure is to open up parts of the wall and run 14/2 to the old light fixture.

Comment: @Otten33, I'm using several [of these lutron switches](https://www.casetawireless.com/products) in my house.  the smart switches have wireless remotes that look like a Decora switch that can be used to control a switch from a second location.  You could have a smart switch on the bottom of the stairs and position the wireless pico remote at the top, and bam, instant 3-way.  Now, I'm not sure if that meets code requirements for a 3-way switch on stairs...

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I have an outlet on the other side of the wall about 6 inches away that is hidden behind a refridgerator.  Can I tap into it for my neutral or is that a big no no?  I would wire up the bottom 3 way switch and light to the outlet's neutral.  Would that work?  Would make things super easy but not sure if my switches would work the way I want them to.

Answer (score 1):

### Smart switch; change one cable

The cable from the existing lamp to the nearer switch (upstairs?)... you need to change that to a /3 cable (red white black).

You can extend the cable to your new lamp from any switch box.  When you do, use colored tape to re-tag the black wire as a red wire.

Now we're going to fit smart switches that allow wireless connection of remotes.  These smart switches cannot require a wire for comms between them, as we lack any spare wires.

Now we're going to change the color codes.  As it happens, the existing color codes will suffice in all locations:

- black = always-hot
- white = neutral
- red = switched-hot

Your master smartswitch attaches to black, white and red.

Your remote smartswitch attaches to black and white only.

Your original lamp connects to red and white.

Your new lamp attaches to red and white in the box nearest it.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify: is there an existing light fixture which is working properly with the existing switches?   If there is, you need to run 2-wire from it to the new fixture and from the new fixture to the existing box on the left in your diagram.  Wire both light fixtures in parallel, i.e. the white return to mains power goes to both, and the black output of the left-hand switch goes to the hot side of both.
This does mean you can't "cheat" as in the diagram which uses a single 2-wire cable for both the mains Hot input and the returning Hot to the light fixtures.

#### edit

To be crystal-clear, another diagram from the same source as the one you posted.
[image: 2lights, 2 switches]

Comment: Yes there is an existing light fixture and 3 way switches that work properly until I try and wire up the new light fixture.  I've tried all kinds of wiring configurations and I can get the lights to work but not properly.  New light will light up and the original light up top will light only dimmly from bottom switch.  From top switch the top light will light up but not the bottom light.

Comment: So I need to run 14/2 from new light to the old light?  Is that the only way?  This is in a staircase where one light is at the top of the stairwell and the other is at the bottom of it.  I can probably reach the left hand switch without to much difficult but the top light might be a PITA.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid so.

Comment: Can I tie into the wiring from the original light before it reaches the light switch on the left?  Meaning right above the left hand light switch or does it have to be from the original power source running to the top light?

Comment: @Otten33 Your main issue is that there is no neutral in the switch box you have the orange arrow going to.  That's why you cant wire directly to that box.  The box that has the first light in it is the only box with a neutral in your diagram.

Comment: So your saying if I wire the new fixture back to the box on the left, connect my neutrals together, I should be golden?

Comment: Carl:  My power source is coming from my light on the 2nd story floor.  It would be difficult to run the wiring from the top light to the bottom light without punching several holes in the wall which if I have to, I will.

Comment: That diagram you added is not his topology, not nearly.  3ways are hard.

Comment: @harper -- I know!  He needs to rebuild his topology.   There are other layout options at the same website, BTW>